# PowerShell Parameter Sets: Require either A or B to be set

Tags: powershell, parameters

Is there a simple way to have a parameter set that allows either A or B but not both to be specified?

E.G. My script will either accept:

```
.\SimpleScript.ps1 -A "str1" -X 1 -Y 2 -Z 3
```

or

```
.\SimpleScript.ps1 -B "str2" -X 1 -Y 2 -Z 3
```

but not:

```
.\SimpleScript.ps1 -A "str1" -B "str2" -X 1 -Y 2 -Z 3
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can write a CmdLet and use [Parameter sets](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2011/06/30/use-parameter-sets-to-simplify-powershell-commands/).

Have a look to the base documentation at [About Functions Advanced Parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters)

```
Param
(
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true,
    ParameterSetName="WithA")]
    [String]
    $A,

    [parameter(Mandatory=$true,
    ParameterSetName="WithB")]
    [String]
    $B,

    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [Int]
    $X
...
)
```

Comment: While script cmdlets (now called "advanced functions" in MS parlance) are the "normal" environment for parameter sets, a script (.ps1 file) can also have a decorated `param()` block, including using parameter sets.

Comment: I prefer to write advanced functions as well. It's just that they're not _required_ for the querent's purposes.

Answer (score 8):

You want to use [***Parameter Sets***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parameter_sets) ([archived page](https://web.archive.org/web/20160531010517/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878348(v=vs.85).aspx)). By making `-A` a mandatory parameter in one parameter set and `-B` mandatory in a different parameter set, supplying both `-A` and `-B` will cause PowerShell to be unable to resolve which parameter set you intended, and reject the command (with an error indicating that it couldn't resolve the parameter set). Look at [this Scripting Guy column](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2011/06/30/use-parameter-sets-to-simplify-powershell-commands/) for an example.